# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage (WindowsAzure.Storage) 9.1.1 failing on call to Newtonsoft outside of its dependency

Tags: azure, json.net, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

- I am using WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.1.
- It states that it has a dependency on Newtonsoft >= 10.0.2
- I'm using .NET Framework 4.5
- I have Newtonsoft 11.0.2 installed
- When I execute the following code there is an exception on table.ExecuteBatch

*InnerException {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=**10.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}  System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}*

```
    public void TableStorageDemo()
    {
        storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection");

        tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TABLE_NAME");

        TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

        var entity = new Entity();
        entity.Test = "Hello World";

        batchOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);

        if (batchOperation.Count() > 0) table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
    }
```

Why is the it looking for 10.0.0.0 when it has a dependency on Newtonsoft >= 10.0.2

I have tried with various versions of WindowsAzure.Storage and it only works when using version 8.7.0 which has a dependency on Newtonsoft >= 6.0.8

I am running this from an Azure Function. (I have followed the suggestion at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk to allow Azure Functions to run with a version of Newtonsoft > 9.0.1) Note that it is not the Function complaining about the Newtonsoft dependency - it is WindowsAzure.Storage. The Function runs correctly with Newtonsoft 11.0.2 and WindowsAzure.Storage 8.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also could reproduce it on my side. if I use the WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.1 ,Newtonsoft  11.0.2  and Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13 in the `Azure function App`.

It seems the **Function App SDK dependency related issue**. If WindowsAzure.Storage **8.7.0 or 7.2.1** is possible, you could use that as workaround.

The issue that it seems not related to  WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.1 itself. 
As  WindowsAzure.Storage 9.1.1 and Newtonsoft  11.0.2  are working correctly in the `console application`.

You could raise [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues) in the github.

Comment: Thanks for your diagnosis. Issue raised in Github. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/194

Comment: With above github issue link, seems like issue downgrading WindowsAzure.Storage is the only option. Let me know if you tried anything else other than downgrading. @fanetic